# How to thank someone for them being helpful?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is it correct to say:
"Thanks for being a huge help?"

Comment: "Thanks for being (such) a huge help." Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds perfect. Variations might be

> Thanks for being a big help
>
> Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is something you might hear or say.

You might also consider

> 1. Thanks for your/the help.
> 2. Thanks for being so helpful.